# Simplify $A \times (A \times B)$

Tags: cross-product

Where $A$ and $B$ are vectors, and $\times$ is the cross product operator. I was able to get $A(A \cdot B) - B$ using the vector triple product, but it doesn't look like a simplified version to me.

Comment: This does not make sense to me. $\vec A \cdot(\vec A \cdot \vec B)= \vec A \cdot \text{scalar}$ which is ridiculous

Comment: Do you want $\times$ to be the cross product?  Or are you trying to get $A\cdot (A\times B)$, where $\cdot$ is dot product and $\times$ is cross product?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant x is the cross product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly note that, the vector triple product you want to evaluate is actually:
$$A \times (A \times B)=(A\cdot B)A-(|A|^2)B$$

And this is, in fact, the most simplified expression that we can arrive at with what little you have given us!

> Try to prove a more general following result:
>
> $$A \times (B \times C)=(A \cdot C)B-(A \cdot B)C$$
>
> **Hint**: Take, $A=a_1\hat i+a_2 \hat j+a_3 \hat k$ and so on for other vectors and do brute force computation.